# Removing layers of geom_smooth in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot a temporal graph of different variables within a single plot by this code:

```
landu<-getField(source =landuseh,var = "LU", cover.threshold = 0.01, spatial.extent = mountains, spatial.extent.id = "SEA" )
year<-selectYears(x = landu, first = 1750, last = 2100)
datalu<-as.data.frame(yearssel1)

aggregate1<-aggregateSpatial(yearssel1)
print(aggregate1)
p<-plotTemporal(aggregate1,layers=c("CL","PA", "NA"))
```

The code above is done through DGVMTools package in R.

```
plot2<-p+theme_classic()+labs(y= "Fraction", x = "Year")+
  ggtitle("",subtitle ="")+guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = theme_get()$text$size * 1.2))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1))
```

[image: ggplot]

The geom_smooth is automatically plotted (I never passed a command to plot it).
The layers of my ggplot are :

```
plot2$layers
[[1]]
geom_smooth: se = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE, orientation = NA, flipped_aes = FALSE
stat_smooth: method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE, n = 80, fullrange = FALSE, level = 0.95, na.rm = FALSE, orientation = NA, method.args = list(), span = 0.75
position_identity 

[[2]]
geom_line: na.rm = FALSE, orientation = NA, flipped_aes = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

How can I remove the geom smooth lines? And just keep those lines that are behind the geom smooth shades?

Comment: Where are the codes of the `p` ?

Comment: I added the codes through the edit

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please provide a reproducible code with the packages you have use as `library(ggplot2)`.